# Приостановка звука в кадре Flash. ActionScript 2.

Tags: аудио, flash, actionscript

Я столкнулся с одной проблемой. Есть задание, сделать мультик и к нему управляющие кнопки: старт, пауза, выкл звук, вкл звук.

Пауза и возобновление мультика происходит через _root.play() и _root.stop()

Проблема возникла со звуком: у него есть два метода sound.start() и sound.stop(), но при вызове sound.stop(), и потом при sound.start(), аудиозапись сбрасывается на начальную позицию, и начинает играть заново. А мне нужно начинать с той позиции, где приостановил. Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите [описание объекта Sound](http://docs.brajeshwar.com/as2/Sound.html).

У меня примерно такое получается. Функции чисто для читаемости кода, могут быть ляпы, нечасто в наше время AS2 встречается)

```
var pos = 0, // последняя позиция проигрывателя, ms
    sound = MySoundObject; // объект со звуком

function playMySound() {
  sound.start(pos / 1000); // start( secondOffset:Number )
}
function stopMySound() {
  pos = sound.position;
  sound.stop();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, я как-то пропустил метод position :)

Примечание: вместо .play - .start

Comment: Пожалуйста) Исправил start. 

ЗЫ: position - не метод, свойство :)